# Is there any case in which evaluation of outliers does not render probabilistic sampling deterministic?

Tags: outliers, assumptions, randomness

As I understand it, probability sampling means that every element in the population has a nonzero probability of being selected as part of the sample. But when some elements have a nonzero probability of being removed from the sample, it means not every element in the population has a nonzero probability of being included in the sample, prior to the sample data being processed by a statistical test. Also, it is pointless to evaluate outliers unless the probability of acting on the results of such an evaluation is nonzero. In contrast, the probability of pruning or treating unevaluated elements (inliers) is zero. Hence, just looking for outliers is akin to selective profiling, and seems to violate the assumption that a sample is a random sample.

Some helpful definitions of true and false outliers etc found in "A review of approaches for the detection and treatment of outliers in processing wind turbine and windfarm measurements.
M. Zou, S Djokic, ENERGIES 2020 13 (6) 4228 PUBLISHED 15 August 2020

Comment: I find this unclear. How does looking for outliers violate simple random sampling? There are various things you can do when looking for outliers, above just removing them.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's helpful to consider what you would do if you had the entire population.  The basic idea of design-based inference is that you have an estimation procedure that you wish you could run on the population, but you can't. Instead, you run it on a probability sample. Your goal is to estimate the same thing that you would estimate given the population.

Suppose you would, given the population, compute a robust location estimator such as the median or a trimmed mean or a mean trimmed at $\pm 2$ times a robust scale estimator, or otherwise delete the outliers.  In that case you should do the same thing for your probability sample: the trimmed/winsorised/outlier-deleted summary of the sample will estimate the same thing as the same estimator of the population.

This would be a reasonable thing to do if, for example, you suspected that the variable was subject to gross measurement errors and wanted the mean of the non-erroneous values, or if you thought the variable would be long-tailed and you wanted a good estimate of its centre.

On the other hand, if you would just take the mean of the population, that's what you should do to the sample. If you instead delete outliers, you're not really taking advantage of the probability sample. Whether you say it isn't *really* a probability sample anymore is a semantic point. My guess is that the majority use of the words would be that it is still a probability sample, but that's just a guess.

Comment: Presume I have complete unknowledge of the population. I am a blind analyst. The parameter of interest is the Extremal Quotient (EQ). Sampling randomly and then removing deviates (by whatever process) because they are very large, even though I have no knowledge of whether they are true or false outliers (see Zou &Djokic above); might that bias my sample statistic (i.e. underestimate the population EQ)?

Comment: I didn't assume you knew anything about the population, just about *what analysis you would do* if you had the population data. If you don't know, a probability sample isn't going to help.